# Adding referrals to links

Tags: php, xml, rss, href, setattribute

I'm trying to dynamically add a link to the beginning of all the links in an RSS feed.

So far I have this which looks to me like it should work. What am I missing here?

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$url = $_GET['url']; 

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load("$url"); 
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
$link->setAttribute('href', 'http://$id.refsite/url/' . $link->getAttribute('href'));
}
echo $xml->saveXML();
?>
```

edit : .. this section doesn't appear to be doing anything

```
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
$link->setAttribute('href', 'http://$id.refsite/url/' . $link->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Comment: I don't know, what doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't add anything to the links

Comment: Is the $url pointing to the same server ?

Comment: You should use `loadHTMLFile` instead of `load` if you are planning on manipulating HTML, with the corresponding `saveHTML` method.

Comment: I can't use loadHTMLfile because messes up the XML formating

Comment: @DeadLizard: `<a href="">` looks like HTML. Is the document XHTML then?

Comment: rss feeds are supposed to be XML right ...

Answer (score 0):

try to use `removeAttribute` and after `setAttribute` the href like :

```
    $get_url =  $link->getAttribute('href');
    $newURL= "http://$id.refsite/url/".$get_url;

    //remove and set href attribute       
    $link->removeAttribute('href');
    $link->setAttribute("href", $newURL);
```

Comment: $url is the rss feed location

Comment: ok i update this, this is an example, you can look on the idea

Comment: nope it's still acting like nothing's happening in the middle :(

Answer (score 0):

Just answered my own question.
This is what I was trying to do

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $url = $_GET['url']; 
    $page = file_get_contents("$url");
    $pagefixed = str_replace("http://","http://$id.refsite/url/","$page");
    echo $pagefixed;

?>
```

sometimes you just have a moment, lol